# DBT Redshift Unload Macro Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt, unload

I am attempting to use the Redshift Package Macro for Unloading to S3. When I compile the code and run it directly in Redshift it works fine, but dbt keeps failing when I run model or build model.

Here is the dbt code:

```
{{
  config(
      {
        "post-hook": [
            "{{ redshift.unload_table('analytics_dev_josh',
                            'stg_payment_transaction',
                            s3_path='s3://bucket/folder',
                            iam_role='arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxx',
                            header=True,
                            delimiter=',',
                            overwrite=true) }}"
            ]
        }
    )
}}
```

Here is the compiled code:

```
  -- compile UNLOAD statement
  UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM "analytics_dev_josh"."stg_payment_transaction"')
  TO 's3://bucket/folder'  
  IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxx'  
  HEADER  
  DELIMITER AS ','  
  NULL AS ''
  MAXFILESIZE AS 6 GB  
  ESCAPE  
  ALLOWOVERWRITE  
  PARALLEL OFF
```

Here is the error:

```
14:03:06  Began running node model.analytics.unload_test
14:03:06  1 of 1 START sql table model analytics_dev_josh.unload_test .................... [RUN]
14:03:06  Acquiring new redshift connection 'model.analytics.unload_test'
14:03:06  Began compiling node model.analytics.unload_test
14:03:06  Writing injected SQL for node "model.analytics.unload_test"
14:03:06  Timing info for model.analytics.unload_test (compile): 2023-02-27 14:03:06.181313 => 2023-02-27 14:03:06.184251
14:03:06  Began executing node model.analytics.unload_test
14:03:06  Writing runtime sql for node "model.analytics.unload_test"
14:03:06  Using redshift connection "model.analytics.unload_test"
14:03:06  On model.analytics.unload_test: BEGIN
14:03:06  Opening a new connection, currently in state closed
14:03:06  Redshift adapter: Connecting to Redshift using 'database' credentials
14:03:06  SQL status: BEGIN in 0 seconds
14:03:06  Using redshift connection "model.analytics.unload_test"
14:03:06  On model.analytics.unload_test: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.4.3", "profile_name": "user", "target_name": "default", "node_id": "model.analytics.unload_test"} */

  
    

  create  table
    "domusodatawarehouse"."analytics_dev_josh"."unload_test__dbt_tmp"
    
    
    
  as (
    
  );
  
14:03:06  Postgres adapter: Postgres error: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 13:   );
           ^
14:03:06  On model.analytics.unload_test: ROLLBACK
14:03:06  Timing info for model.analytics.unload_test (execute): 2023-02-27 14:03:06.184611 => 2023-02-27 14:03:06.337104
14:03:06  On model.analytics.unload_test: Close
14:03:06  Database Error in model unload_test (models/stage/unload_test.sql)
  syntax error at or near ")"
  LINE 13:   );
             ^
  compiled Code at target/run/analytics/models/stage/unload_test.sql
14:03:06  Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'run_model', 'label': '5db3e73a-88f6-4c8c-bd6f-570e08d52b43', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fce41a11130>]}
14:03:06  1 of 1 ERROR creating sql table model analytics_dev_josh.unload_test ........... [ERROR in 0.16s]
14:03:06  Finished running node model.analytics.unload_test
```

When I cut and paste the compiled code from dbt into redshift directly, it works as required.  But when I run the code in dbt, I get the error.  Its looks as if dbt is trying to put data into a temp table with the unload statement and it is throwing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to run this as a post-hook command on top of a DBT model. DBT will first run your `unload_test` model to build a table with the same name and then the post-hook runs after that first step is complete. Your model is empty which is what is causing the failure.

Usually, you would run a post-hook on a model to take action on the table after it's built. In your case, you should be running the post-hook in the `stg_payment_transaction` model. If you don't have a model for this (or don't have access to it because it's in another project), you can move your post-hook to `on-run-end` in `dbt_project.yml`

Comment: The solution was to put the post-hook on the correct table.  Thank you.